# How to convert RGB images to grayscale, expand dimensions of that grayscale image to use in InceptionV3?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, data-augmentation

I'm training a Keras model and I have training images in RGB format. I want to train my model but on grayscale images on InceptionV3, but it takes RGB images as input. My question is: How can I first convert the RGB images into grayscale, then make a copy in 3 dimensions? I'm using Keras' `TrainDataGenerator.flow_from_directory` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class), you can pass a preprocessing function. Use the functions [`tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/rgb_to_grayscale) and [`tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/grayscale_to_rgb) to do the transformation:

```
def to_grayscale_then_rgb(image):
    image = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image)
    image = tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(image)
    return image
```

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1/255,
    preprocessing_function=to_grayscale_then_rgb
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest way to do is to use the  *color_mode ="grayscale"* parameter of the *TrainDataGenerator.flow_from_directory* method.

Here is the keras online documentation that specifies how to do this
https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/