# Converting RGB Dataset to Grayscale Dataset by averaging color channels with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, keras, tensorflow2

I'm trying to convert a dataset of dimensions (32, 32, 3, 10000) dimension dataset to a grayscale dataset, where I would have (32, 32, 1, 10000) dimensions, but I need to have that 1 channel because I will input this to a Neural Network. I tried using numpy.average, but the shape becomes (32, 32, 10000) which the TensorFlow unit is not taking as an input. I even tried to manually average it, but it had the same result. Could you guys help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert RGB images to grayscale, expand dimensions of that grayscale image to use in InceptionV3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65179822/how-to-convert-rgb-images-to-grayscale-expand-dimensions-of-that-grayscale-imag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to add that extra dimension you need after getting `(32, 32, 1000)` as shape.

You could try [`np.expand_dims`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) with the `axis` parameter to define where you want that extra "1" to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `(0.299 * Red) + (0.587 * Green) + (0.114 ∙ Blue)` instead of averaging.